# Error on details, create view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have made a CRUD application in asp.net MVC 3. The index page is showing all the data from my database fine in a table. However when I click Edit, Details or Delete this the error I get:

```
 The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(Int32)' in 'cpd.Controllers.Default4Controller'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

I have two classes which model my tables. I used code first and below is the code for my classes.

```
 public class cpd_certificates
{

        [Key]
        public int CertificateNo { get; set; }
        public int QuizNo { get; set; }


        public DateTime? DateReceived { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatePaid { get; set; }
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public int? AccreditationNo { get; set; }


        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public virtual cpd_recipients Recipients { get; set; }

}

 public class cpd_recipients
{
        [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OpNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot exceed {1} characters")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public string Address1 {get; set;}
    public string Address2 {get; set;}
    public string Address3 {get; set;}
    public string Address4 {get; set;}
    public string Country {get; set;}

    public string email {get; set;}

}
```

This maps as a 0..1 to many. My fluent API is below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<cpd_certificates>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Recipients);
    }
```

Part of controller code:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        cpd_certificates cpd_certificates = db.Cert.Find(id);
        ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.CPD, "ID", "OpNo", cpd_certificates.ID);
        return View(cpd_certificates);
    }
```

// POST: /Default4/Edit/5

```
 public ActionResult Edit(cpd_certificates cpd_certificates)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(cpd_certificates).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.CPD, "ID", "OpNo", cpd_certificates.ID);
        return View(cpd_certificates);
    }
```

Code from view:

```
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
```

map routes:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Default4", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

How do I solve this error. I am a relatively inexperienced in this.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you are not passing the ID of the object (apparently `recipient`) user wants to manipulate as a parameter of the action. In other words, most likely in your controller you have an action declared like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
```

And when user click Delete, the request sent to the server does not have an `id` parameter in it. To correct this check how are you sending the request, how do you construct the url and whether you are passing the `id` to it correctly.

**Update.** Here is one more way for you to try. Name `id` appears in your routing, however in the action you have specified that `id` will be passed as the parameter of request. This particular issue can be resolved with simple renaming. Rename the parameter of the action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int certId)
```

and make the corresponding update on the view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Default4", new { certId = item.PrimaryKey })
```

This should result in the following url: `/Default4/Edit?certId=5`

Comment: True I have a action declared as you stated. I have edited my post to show how I was sending the request. As stated earlier I a newbabie in this.

Comment: @Sithelo, you have posted the code of the action that receives the request. But the error is most likely in the request itself, or in the way you are sending it (form post or url with query string). Can you post the part of the View that is responsible for this?

Comment: Agree... the problem surely starts with an error on the call to the controller. It could be also referred to the url routing.

Comment: @Sithelo, please see the updated answer. Also note that what you have posted is not the View code but rather the controller that returns the View. View is the file with HTML/Razor/Asp.NET markup in it.

Comment: @andrei Below is the code for the view. https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F6CEA54D10B37C92!108

Comment: @Bardo I have upload the file for your preview.

Comment: @Andrei I have edited the post and included the routing. Please go to the link I posted to view the whole file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19636/discussion-between-sithelo-and-andrei)

Answer (score 0):

As Andrei said, your error is likely in the way you are making the request to the Edit action method. Your action link should look like this in your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "YourControllerName", new { @id = TheIDForTheObject })
```

This should get rid of the error.

If your intention is to allow null values to be passed to the Edit action method (which I doubt, but it's nice to know anyway), then change your action method to allow a nullable id:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    // Your implementation here
}
```